# Como convertir un string a un int

Tags: java

Buen día. Mi problema es el siguiente: estoy realizando un programa donde le pido al usuario que ingrese la fecha. Esta se está guardando en un variable de tipo `String` donde el usuario puede ingresar la fecha de distintas formas. Por ejemplo:

> 13/03/2020 ó 13-02-2020 ó 13,02,2020

Lo que quiero hacer es que la fecha que el usuario proporcionó la convierta a un tipo de dato `int` es decir:

> 13022020

Este es mi código aunque no funciona correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si queres que Integer.parseInt(x) te devuelva 13022020, entonces x tiene que ser un String = "13022020"). Si x es un string no numerico (por ejemplo con /) entonces te va a tirar un NumberFormatException.

Comment: pero entonces como soluciono eso es que me piden que el usuario introduzca la fecha en alguno de estos formatos 13/03/2020 ó 13-02-2020 ó 13,02,2020 después eliminar todo lo que no sea numero ejemplo: "," "-" "/" etc y guardar los numeros como un tipo de dato int

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, la mas artesanal, seria recorrer el string caracter por caracter y guardar en un nuevo string solo datos que son numéricos. Podrias un for, y los métodos length() y charAt() de String para recorrer cada caracter. Los caracteres numéricos son mayores o iguales a '0' y menores o iguales a '9'

Comment: gracias lo voy a intetar

Comment: No se si lo que deseas es volver la respuesta un entero o transformar la fecha como la obtienes a milisegundos. Si es eliminar cualquier simbolo, puedes hacerlo con expresiones regulares.

Comment: Por favor! el codigo **siempre** en formato texto y no en imagen... Para poder ayudarte comparte lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema se puede resolver de varias formas, una de ellas seria aplicar una expresión regular sobre la variable `fecha`.

```
 fecha = fecha.replaceAll("([/,-])","");
```

Con este código reemplazarías todas las ocurrencias de "-" , "/" y "," que se encuentren en tu cadena de texto.

Por ultimo casteamos a `int` tal y como tienes hecho

```
numeroentero = Integer.parseInt(fecha)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió mucho tu respuesta lo pude solucionar con el replaceAll

Comment: Si mi respuesta te resolvio el problema , no dudes en marcarla como aceptada :)